# Can I connect two LED lights to the same power driver?

Tags: lighting, led, transformer

I have two Lights (12V, 18W each) originally designed to be installed in automobiles (trucks for flood lights). I want to use them as work lights and install them both on the same support. I would like to power them through my home electrical system (110vac). Could I power them both from the same LED Driver so long as that LED driver was rated beyond 36W (18Wx2)? How should I connect them together (i.e. before entering the DC input on the power driver or at the power driver input)? Thank you. 
These are the lights: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00W6QBJNI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00W6QBJNI)

Comment: You probably don't want a "LED driver", as these units seem designed to regulate the power supplied to them. Just a 12V/3+A supply itself would work.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the specifications given for those Lights, an LED driver is not what you need.

They're listed as supporting "10-30v DC Voltage", which means that they must have their own LED driver circuitry already inside them, so all you need to supply is an appropriate DC voltage in that range from a power supply which can handle the load.

You are correct that the supply (driver) must be rated for at least 36W to support both of the lights, so for example if you have a 12V supply, it must be able to provide at least 3A (since 12V x 3A = 36W). If you use a 24V supply, then 1.5A will be enough.

Once you have an appropriate supply, connect the lights in parallel to its output (that's + from both lights going together to + out from supply and - from both lights going together to - from supply).